# Windows Azure GZIP for ASP.Net MVC Web Site

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, gzip, azure-web-app-service

I've been tearing my hair out trying to get GZIP compression to work for a standard Azure Web Site which is using ASP.NET MVC 5.

Does anybody have a definitive guide to setting up the web.config or applying a custom attribute?

I've tried everything I usually use locally such as supplying GZIP/DEFLATE content encoding header but to no avail.

I'm beginning to think it doesn't work in the standard web site but I thought I should ask first..

Cheers

-- Update.

I am not getting any errors, (I as far as I can tell) am checking the Accept-Encoding header, and adding a Content-encoding header in return with the value gzip. However when I try to check the headers in Chrome/Firefox on the live site it does not seem to be working.

e.g. Locally

```
 GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:34249
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Pragma: no-cache
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
    Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4

Cache-Control:public, max-age=15
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:22900
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 20:18:47 GMT
Expires:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 20:19:00 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 20:18:45 GMT
Vary:*,Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcV29ya1xCbG9nXEJsb2c=?=
```

On Azure...

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:ARRAffinity=2f6641fa653941a3835129cf27dd73a8f366413851cb89c13e53d88bf9cadc19
Host:<bla>
Pragma:no-cache
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36

Cache-Control:public, max-age=8
Content-Length:44549
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 20:20:03 GMT
Expires:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 20:20:12 GMT
Last-Modified:Wed, 13 Aug 2014 20:19:57 GMT
Vary:*,Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options:DENY
```

As you can see no content encoding parameter. Let me know if you need any more information. Cheers J

Comment: Can you please include more details to help us answer your question?  What commands are you running and what are the exact errors that you're seeing?

Comment: Could you post the section of your web.config? Something like this: http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info/#http-compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I thought I had already closed the question. It seems I was going through a proxy which was stripping out GZIP in this particular example.

SyntaxC4 - Many thanks for the cheat sheet I'm sure it will become useful later if I require IP blocking.

Cheers,
J